# Insufficient permissions to run IE8 and Adobe Reader

Tags: windows-xp, permissions

I am using Windows XP Home Edition. I downloaded a few programs

- Adobe Reader
- Internet Explorer 8

The download is O.K., but when I attempt to run the applications, a message comes up `insufficient permissions`.

I have checked and my user account is an administrator, but the problem persists.

I am a computer novice, so I need to request step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have permission to install to where you're trying, try a different location. Also try running the installer [as administrator](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_security_runas.mspx?mfr=true), though you say your account is so just enter your own log in credentials. If this doesn't work a network administrator may have place restrictions on your account. Is this a home computer or a work computer?

Comment: Hi Celeritas !!  Thank you for the response. I have downloaded and run / installed a number of programs until recently using the same procedure as now, with no problems. I am logged on as an administrator, It is a home computer and I am the only user. I obviously must have done something wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: Try installing something else you had success with in the past. If it doesn't work then you know something has been changed that's not allowing you to install things.

Comment: Thanks Celeritas !! You are quick to respond, thanks again. I had some time ago already installed I E 8 and run it O.K. but then I removed IE 8 as I wanted to use Chrome. I don't know why I removed it, maybe because I'm doff. Now, IE 8 won't run. Ken

Comment: How did you remove IE 8? You realize it's not in the normal uninstaller and is part of Windows. Its unadvisable to uninstall internet explorer because it's so closly integrated into Windows. The simpolist solution is to use anoter browser.

Comment: Hi Celeritas, sorry about the delay, but I've been ill. I did install Google Chrome some time ago, and the problem has occurred recently, while I have been using Chrome. I have downloaded and run programs through Chrome until recently, say the last month. Regards - Ken